# Laying out the views

Tags: android, view

I have played around but haven`t found the solution.
I need Layout to be at the bottom of its parent.
Here is a code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/Q1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:text="@string/true_button_text"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:text="@string/false_button_text"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:contentDescription="Back"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:contentDescription="Next"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I need the last two **ImageButton** be at the bottom.
The attribute **android:layout_gravity="bottom"** doesn`t help
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using RelativeLayout is best approach in this case but in case you don't want to switch to the RelativeLayout, and want to stick to LinearLayout, you can assign '***android:layout_weight="1"***'to the linear layout just above the linear layout containing the "imagebuttons".
**Caution :** Though this way you'll be able to push the image buttons at the bottom, this will fill your rest of the screen with the layout just above it (in this case, the one containing the "buttons").
**NOTE:** This approach is very useful in the cases where one wants to place a layout (containing buttons or anything) right at the bottom of the screen containing a list.
**EDIT:** It just struck me that you can even put an empty linearLayout just above the one containing the imagebuttons and set the attribute '***android:layout_weight="1"***' in this newly added layout. This way even the buttons don't take the full screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="QI" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/true_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/false_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Back"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Next"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Note: Replace my drawable with yours, try and let me know, is this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a relativeLayout as the parent layout instead and also set the layout_gravity property in the linearlayout containing the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

try this too with linear layout `weight` and `weighSum` Properties

just play with `layout_weight` to satisfy ur requirement

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Q1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="true_button_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="false_button_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Back"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Next"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

hope it works fo u.....